# set @State var inside geometryReader

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

How is it possible to set a @State var inside a geometryReader?

This is my code:

```swift
@State var isTest:Int = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ForEach(self.test, id: \.id) { Test in
            VStack{
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    self.isTest = 1
```

I try with a function but it doesn't work.

```
@State var isTest: Int = 0

func testValue() {
    self.isTest = 1
}

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ForEach(self.test, id: \.id) { Test in
            VStack{
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    testValue()
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @State var is equal to geometry width, self.isTest = geometry.size.width. Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

You can use [onAppear(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyView/onAppear(perform:)) to update `@State` variables with the initial view size and [onChange(of:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onChange(of:perform:)) to update the variables when the view size changes:

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State private var size: CGSize = .zero

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack {
        Text("Hello World")
      }.onAppear {
        size = geometry.size
      }.onChange(of: geometry.size) { newSize in
        size = newSize
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple, clean and it works as far as I can tell. The .onAppear trick was mentioned before but .onChange seems necessary to update the geometry when it changes.

Answer (score 4):

While putting code into function is a nice touch, there may arrive another problem and that is altering the @State variable during update phase:
`[SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior`

Using NotificationCenter to move @State variable update *after* view update phase can help, but one could use much more simple solution like performing variable update right after render phase by using `DispatchQueue`.

```
@State var windowSize = CGSize()

func useProxy(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.windowSize = geometry.size
    }

    return EmptyView()
}

var body: some View {

    return GeometryReader { geometry in
        self.useProxy(geometry)    

        Text("Hello SwiftUI")        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem yesterday. But I was trying to pass a value from inside the GeometryReader.

I tried a couple of ways but it didn't work.
When I use `@State var` to declare the variable, the compiler again complained in a purple line saying that Modifying the view during update will make it become Undefined.

When I tried to declare a variable using `var` only, the compiler just told me that it's  immutable.

And then, I tried storing it onto my `@EnvironmentObject`. And I just got a dead loop.

So, my last hope was using the notification way and some how it worked. But I don't know if it's the standard way of implementation.

```
@State private var viewPositionY:CGFloat = 0
```

First, post the value `frame.origin.y` via notification.

```
 GeometryReader{ geometry -> Text in
        let frame = geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("channelBlahblahblah"), object:nil, userInfo:["dict":frame.origin.y])
        return Text("My View Title")
 }
```

And then declare a publisher to receive the notification.

```
private let myPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name("channelBlahblahblah"))
```

Finally, use the the .onReceive modifier to receive the notification.

```
.onReceive(myPublisher) { (output) in
           
   viewPositionY = output.userInfo!["dict"] as! CGFloat
   //you can do you business here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```swift
@State private var viewSize: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // ...
    }
    .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.clear.preference(
            key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self,
            value: proxy.size
        )
    })
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
        viewSize = size
    }
}

private struct ViewSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = value.width + value.height > nextValue().width + nextValue().height ? value : nextValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update `@State` variables in the `onAppear` method if you need the initial geometry values

```
@State var windowSize = CGSize()

var body: some View {

    return GeometryReader { geometry in 
        VStack {
            Text("Hello SwiftUI")  
        }
        .onAppear {
            windowSize = geometry.size
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's totally possible to update a `@State` inside a `GeometryReader`. The solution is simple. However, there's a caveat:

**you might end up with an infinite loop**
(nothing too troublesome, I'll present a solution here)

You'll just need a `DispatchQueue.main.async` and explicitly declare the type of the view inside `GeometryReader`. If you execute the View below (don't forget to stop it) you'll see that it never stops updating the value of the `Text`.

**NOT THE FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
struct GenericList: View {
    @State var timesCalled = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                timesCalled += 1 // infinite loop
            }
            return Text("\(timesCalled)")
        }
    }
}
```

This happens because the View will "draw" the `GeometryReader`, which will update a `@State` of the View. Thus, the new `@State` invalidates the View causing the View to be redrawn. Consequently going back to the first step (drawing the `GeometryReader` and updating the state).

To solve this you need to put some constraints in the draw of the `GeometryReader`. Instead of returning your View inside the `GeometryReader`, draw it then add the `GeometryReader` as a transparent overlay or background. This will have the same effect but you'll be able to put constraints in the presentation.

Personally, I'd rather use an overlay because you can add as many as you want. Note that an overlay does not permit an `if else` inside of it, but it is possible to call a function. That's why there's the `func geometryReader()` below. Another thing is that in order to return different types of Views you'll need to add `@ViewBuilder` before it.

In this code, the GeometryReader is called only once and you get the @State var timesCalled updated.

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
struct GenericList: View {
    @State var timesCalled = 0
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func geometryReader() -> some View {
        if timesCalled < 1 {
            GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    timesCalled += 1
                }
                return Color.clear
            }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(timesCalled)")
            .overlay(geometryReader())
    }
}
```

Note: you don't need to put the same constraints, for example, [in my case](https://github.com/renefx/swiftui_learn/blob/main/SwiftUI%20Learn/Drag%20and%20drop/Game/DragObjectView.swift), I wanted to move the view with the drag gesture. So, I've put the constraints to start when the user touches down and to stop when the user ends the drag gesture.

Comment: Can you skip to the final solution? ;)

Comment: It's actually there, marked with FINAL SOLUTION. The core elements to that are:
`@State var timesCalled = 0` a state to control how many times you want to get the frame (might as well be a bool if you want only one)
    
`@ViewBuilder` - so you can return different types of views in the function
`func geometryReader() -> some View {` - a func that returns the `GeometryReader` or an emptyview
`if timesCalled < 1 {` - at last, the condition to stop getting the frame